# NSArray and initWithTitle method

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

I am trying to create an app, similar to Apple's BirdSighting example ("Your Second iOS App"). Instead of birds I am using subjects, where each subject has a title (`title`), some core topics (`core`) and some case studies (`datacase`). When I try to initialize a subject in my data controller (`SubjectController.m`), I get a warning saying "Expected ':'" on the line starting with `subject = [[Subject alloc]....`. Any ideas - something to do with using Arrays perhaps?

The subject.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Subject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *core;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *datacase;

-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title core:(NSArray *)core datacase:(NSArray *)datacase;

@end
```

Subject.m file:

```
#import "Subject.h"

@implementation Subject

-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title core:(NSArray *)core datacase:(NSArray *)datacase
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    _title = title;
    _core = core;
    _datacase = datacase;
    return self;
}
return nil;
}

@end
```

SubjectController.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Subject;

@interface SubjectController : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *masterSubjectList;

-(NSUInteger)countOfList;
-(Subject *)objectInListAtIndex:(NSInteger)theIndex;
-(void)addSubjectWithSubject:(Subject *)subject;

@end
```

SubjectController.m:

```
#import "SubjectController.h"
#import "Subject.h"

@interface SubjectController ()

-(void)createSubjectList;

@end

@implementation SubjectController

-(id) init {
if (self = [super init]) {
    [self createSubjectList];
    return self;
}
return nil;
}

-(void)createSubjectList {
NSMutableArray *subjectList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.masterSubjectList = subjectList;
Subject *subject;
subject = [[Subject alloc] initWithTitle:@"Maths" core:@"Introduction", @"Adding", @"Subtracting" datacase:@"Case 1", @"Case 2", @"Case 3", nil];
[self addSubjectWithSubject:subject];

}

-(void)setMasterSubjectList:(NSMutableArray *)newList {
if (_masterSubjectList != newList) {
    _masterSubjectList = [newList mutableCopy];
}
}

-(NSUInteger)countOfList {
return [self.masterSubjectList count];
}

-(Subject *)objectInListAtIndex:(NSInteger)theIndex {
return [self.masterSubjectList objectAtIndex:theIndex];
}

-(void)addSubjectWithSubject:(Subject *)subject {
[self.masterSubjectList addObject:subject];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing comma-separated lists of `NSString` literals as a parameter to a method where the expected type is an `NSArray` instance. The closest valid syntax to what you want is probably:

```
subject = [[Subject alloc] initWithTitle:@"Maths" core:@[@"Introduction", @"Adding", @"Subtracting"] datacase:@[@"Case 1", @"Case 2", @"Case 3"]];
```

Note that each comma-separated list of strings is now surrounded with square brackets, and the first bracket is preceded by an `@`, and the terminating `nil` is removed from the second list. This is the syntax for an Objective-C literal, and more can be found in the [Clang documentation on Objective-C literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 NSArray *core = [NSArray arrayWithObjects::@"Introduction", @"Adding", @"Subtracting", nil];
 NSArray *datasource = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Case 1", @"Case 2", @"Case 3", nil];
 subject = [[Subject alloc] initWithTitle:@"Maths" core:core datacase:datasource];
```

instead of:

```
 subject = [[Subject alloc] initWithTitle:@"Maths" core:@"Introduction", @"Adding", @"Subtracting" datacase:@"Case 1", @"Case 2", @"Case 3", nil];
```